Does $ \frac{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{\cos(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)}{\cos(\gamma-\alpha)}$ have an analytical solution for $\alpha$?
The equation is about $\alpha$:
$$ \frac{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{\cos(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)}{\cos(\gamma-\alpha)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are given. I failed to transform it with identities and separate the $\alpha$.
This equation was derived when I was solving a geometrical problem for my project:

$\mathrm{AB}$ is an object on the screen with its center labeled as $\mathrm{C}$, and $\mathrm{O}$ represents for the observer, whose distance to the screen is $d$. Given the visual angle $\theta$ that $\mathrm{AB}$ is set to subtend to the observer and its lateral offset angle $\gamma$, I want to determine the size $l$ of $\mathrm{AB}$. I will describe the process in case it helps.
The $\alpha$ in $\eqref{1}$, aka. $\angle{\mathrm{AOC}}$, is an intermediate I used. In $\triangle\mathrm{OAC}$, according to the Law of Sines, we have
$$\frac{\mathrm{AC}}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{\mathrm{OA}}{\sin\angle\mathrm{OCA}} \tag{2}$$
Similarly in $\triangle\mathrm{OBC}$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{BC}}{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}=\frac{\mathrm{OB}}{\sin\angle\mathrm{OCB}} \tag{3}$$
Considering that $\mathrm{AC}=\mathrm{BC}$ and $\angle\mathrm{OCA}+\angle\mathrm{OCB}=\pi$, we know that
$$\frac{\mathrm{OA}}{\mathrm{OB}}=\frac{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}{\sin\alpha} \tag{4}\label{4}$$
On the other hand, $\triangle\mathrm{ODA}$ and $\triangle\mathrm{ODB}$ have a common right-angle side $\mathrm{OD}$, so
$$\frac{\mathrm{OA}}{\mathrm{OB}}=\frac{\mathrm{OD}/\cos(\gamma-\alpha)}{\mathrm{OD}/\cos(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)}=\frac{\cos(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)}{\cos(\gamma-\alpha)} \tag{5}\label{5}$$
Then bridging $\eqref{4}$ and $\eqref{5}$ will lead to $\eqref{1}$. And it's obviously one step away from getting $l$ if $\alpha$ is determined.

What do you mean by "analytic?"

@ThomasAndrews Maybe a function expression to express $\alpha$ with $\gamma$ and $\theta$

Okay, you want a closed formula. "Analytic
" can sometimes be read as including numeric solutions - ways to calculate the solution via an algorithm that can get arbitrary precision.

Equivalent to the geometric question: $$2\tan(\gamma)=\tan(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)-\tan(\gamma+\theta-\alpha).$$ This is because, in coordinate geometry, $A=(d,d\tan(\gamma-\alpha)), C=(d,\tan\gamma),  B=(d,d\tan(\theta+\gamma-\alpha)).$

Short answer:
$$\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac1{\cot\theta-\tan\gamma+\sqrt{\tan^2\gamma+\cot^2\theta+1}}\right)$$
is the positive $\alpha.$
Directly from the geometric question, if we write in coordinate geometry, with $OD$ the $x$-axis, then $A=(d,d\tan(\gamma-\alpha)),$ $C=(d,d\tan \gamma),$ $B=(d,d\tan(\gamma+\theta-\alpha)),$ then you get the equation:
$$2\tan(\gamma)=\tan(\gamma-\alpha)+\tan(\theta+\gamma-\alpha).\tag1$$
Using $\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B},$ we let $X=\tan(\gamma-\alpha)$ and we get:
$$2\tan\gamma=X+\frac{\tan\theta+X}{1-X\tan\theta}$$
This gives you a quadratic equation for $X.$ Letting $t=\tan\theta, g=\tan\gamma,$ you get:
$$tX^2-2(tg+1)X+(2g-t)=0$$
So you get:
$$X=\frac{2(1+tg)\pm\sqrt{4t^2g^2+8tg+4-4t(2g-t)}}{2t}\\=\frac{1+tg\pm\sqrt{t^2g^2+t^2+1}}{t}$$
If $t'=t^{-1}=\cot\theta,$ this becomes:
$$X=t'+g\pm\sqrt{g^2+t'^2+1}$$
That's gonna give a very gross formula, with $\alpha=\gamma-\arctan X,$ namely:
$$\alpha = \gamma-\arctan\left(\cot\theta+\tan\gamma \pm \sqrt{\cot^2\theta+\tan^2\gamma+1}\right)$$
But $$\begin{align}\tan(\alpha)&=\tan(\gamma-\arctan X)\\&=\frac{g-X}{1+gX}\\
&=\frac{-t'\mp\sqrt{g^2+t'^2+1}}{1+gt'+g^2\pm g\sqrt{g^2+t'^2+1}}\\&=\frac{(g-t')\mp\sqrt{1+g^2+t'^2}}{2gt'+1}
\end{align} $$
where the last step is a nasty rationalize the denominator step.
Actually, we get a slightly simpler formula if we rationalize the numerator:
$$\tan(\alpha)=-\frac{1}{(g-t')\pm\sqrt{1+g^2+t'^2}}$$ which, for the positive value, gives:
$$\cot(\alpha)=(t'-g)+\sqrt{g^2+t'^2+1}$$
This gives two $\alpha$ values, one with $\alpha$ positive and one with $\alpha$ negative.
When $\gamma+\theta=\frac\pi2,$ we get $t'=g$ and get:
$$\alpha = \pm\arctan \frac1{\sqrt{1+2\tan^2\gamma}}.$$

A similar approach starts with $(1)$ and uses $A=\tan\alpha,$ and you get:
$$2\tan \gamma = \frac{\tan\gamma -A}{1+A\tan\gamma}+\frac{\tan(\gamma+\theta)-A}{1+A\tan(\gamma+\theta)}.$$
You again get a quadratic equation, her in terms of $g=\tan\gamma$ and $b=\tan(\gamma+\theta).$
So you get $$2g(1+Ag)(1+Ab)=(g-A)(1+Ab)+(b-A)(1+Ag)$$ or $$(2g^2b+g+b)A^2+2(g^2+1)A+(g-b)$$
The discriminant is $$4(1+g^2)^2-4(g-b)(2g^2b+g+b)=4(g^4-2g^3b+2g^2b^2+g^2+b^2+1)$$ and you get:
$$\tan\alpha =\frac{-(1+g^2)\pm\sqrt{g^2(g-b)^2+(g^2+1)(b^2+1)}}{2g^2b+g+b}\\=\frac{b-g}{(g^2+1)\pm\sqrt{g^2(b-g)^+(b^2+1)(g^2+1)}}$$
When $\alpha+\theta=\frac{\pi}2,$ you get $b=+\infty,$ so you should multiply this equation by $b^{-1}$ and get:
$$(2g^2+1)A^2-1=0,$$ which gives the same result as before:
$$\tan\alpha=A=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{1+2\tan^2\gamma}}$$
The general formula for $(2)$ is messy - the discriminant is ugly. Something like: $$D=g^2\left((g-b)^2+b^2+1\right)+b^2+1.$$
But it isn't that much worse, computationally.

Thank you so much but I'm afraid there's a mistake. The nominator on the right side of original Eq. (1) was $\cos(\gamma-\alpha)$, which you mistook for $\cos(\theta-\alpha)$  in the first step of cross mutiplying. So we cannot use $2\sin C\cos C=\sin(2C)$ then.

@StevenHo ok, fixed with an answer.

Brilliant ! Just checked in MATLAB, the $\alpha$s from the two expressions ($X(g,t)$ and $A(g,b)$) were totally consistent. Thanks a lot.

You can rewrite your Equation (1) as
$$\sin\!\left(A-B\right)\cos\!\left(A+B\right)=-\sin\!\left(A-C\right)\cos\!\left(A+C\right)$$
with
$$A=\frac12\left(\theta+\gamma-2\alpha\right)\,,\quad B=\frac12\left(\gamma-\theta\right)\,,\quad C=\frac12\left(\gamma+\theta\right)\,.$$
Using $\sin\!\left(A-B\right)=\sin A \cos B-\cos A \sin B$ and $\cos\!\left(A+B\right)=\cos A \cos B-\sin A\sin B$ and multiplying out, the left-hand side becomes
$$\sin A\cos A-\sin B \cos B = \frac12 \sin2A-\frac12\sin2B\,.$$
Similarly, the RHS becomes
$$-\sin A\cos A+\sin C \cos C = -\frac12 \sin2A+\frac12\sin2C\,.$$
Combining, we get
$$\sin2A=\frac12\left(\sin2B+\sin2C\right)\,,$$
i.e.,
$$\alpha=\frac12\left(\theta+\gamma\right)-\frac12\arcsin\!\left[\frac12\left(\sin2B+\sin2C\right)\right]\,.$$
Crosschecks:

For $\theta=\arctan\!\left(2\tan\gamma\right)$, we get $\alpha=\gamma$ (checked numerically).
For $\theta=0$, we have $\alpha=0$.
For $\gamma=0$, we have $\alpha=\frac12\theta$.

Note that numerically, this seems to be identical to Thomas Andrews' answer, but I did not check this algebraically.

Tnat last formula seems to only rely on $\gamma+\theta.$ I don't think that is correct. You've left out all your steps in between, so we can't check them.

In particular, when I set $\theta,\gamma$ to be $30^\circ, 60^\circ,$ I get $\alpha\approx -37.76^\circ,$ but when $\theta,\gamma$ equal to $40^\circ,50^\circ,$ I get $\alpha\approx 32.80^\circ.$

@ThomasAndrews You're right, I mixed up something. Corrected now

The substitution in the first step is so skillful. Checked the solution and it's consistent with Andrew's (at least when $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are acute and that's enough for me). Thanks!
